# Confusion over radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm iterating over radio buttons previous neighbors. My html looks like this :

```
<div class="holder">
<span class="">some text</span>
<input type="radio" name="test_capability" value="primary" checked="" />
</div>

<div class="holder">
<span class="">some text</span>
<input type="radio" name="test_capability" value="primary" checked="checked" />
</div>

<div class="holder">
<span class="">some text</span>
<input type="radio" name="test_capability" value="primary" checked="" />
</div>
```

I'm trying to add class `red` to span whose neighbor radio button is checked. Here is how I tried :

```
$('.holder span').each(function(){
                var spanElement = $(this);
                if(spanElement.nextAll(':radio:first').is(':checked')){
                    spanElement.addClass("red");
                }
            });
```

I always end up with last span (the one in third holder div) having class `red`. But as you can see the middle one is checked. Same thing happens when I set `checked=checked` on first span

**Update**

Tried also :

```
$('.holder span').each(function(){
                if($(this).next().attr("checked") == "checked"){
                    $(this).addClass("red");
                }
            });
```

Same result, don't know what else to try.

**Update II**:

Html get rendered with previous information generated from server side, so there can only one `checked=checked` radio input element once html is created.

I'm doing this iteration trough span in document ready function.

Comment: a jsFiddle might help in the future to explain the issue.

Comment: .attr("checked") == "checked" does not always work with radio buttons. Use instead: .is(':checked')

Comment: Do you mean to set it on check, and clear the previous? As your code works on load.

Comment: @jcolebrand again I get last span turn red, I want the middle one to turn red because it's next radio is checked

Comment: So you want it to change as each is clicked? So you need something that monitors the click, removes the previous "red" and sets the next one/

Comment: @jcolebrand I have only one set at a time so I can avoid that right? this is on page load, I set it to checked or not before page is loaded

Comment: Then you should specify this, and how do you know it shouldn't change before page load? (say, on check)

Comment: I'm sorry I'll update the question, I should have mentioned that

Comment: I think the problem is the last checkbox is always checked regardless where checked="checked" attribute is located.  To fix this remove checked="" from non-checked element and only use checked attribute only.  See updated jsfiddle.net/eBeNe/3.

Comment: spot on Jules can you please answer I will accept thanks

Comment: Glad to help you. That's enough :).

Comment: it's not all about reputation someone (beside me) will find your answer very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the checked input and add class to it's sibling span element.

```
$('.holder input[type=radio]:checked').prev('span').addClass('red')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TdR7k/

In case that you want to add and remove the classes on change event you can try the following:

```
$('.holder input[type=radio]').change(function() {
     $('.red').removeClass('red');
     $(this).prev('span').addClass('red')
}).change()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dSv6P/

Comment: Revised request, he wants the previous red removed on check

Answer (score 1):

Try this change:

```
$('.holder span').each(function(){
                var spanElement = $(this);
                if(spanElement.next('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')){
                    spanElement.addClass("red");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you define the radio buttons, do not include the checked attribute in the html or they will be checked by default
example: http://jsfiddle.net/TdR7k/1/

```
<div class="holder">
<span class="">some text</span>
<input type="radio" name="test_capabiy" value="primary" checked="" />
</div>

<div class="holder">
<span class="">some text</span>
<input type="radio" name="test_capability" value="primary" checked="checked" />
</div>

<div class="holder">
<span class="">some text</span>
<input type="radio" name="test_capabiliy" value="primary" checked  />
</div>​
```

All three are checked

The proper definition of a radio button is

```
<input type="radio" name="(Group)" value="(etc)"  />
```

And to check it by default, all that is required:

```
<input type="radio" name="(Group)" value="(etc)" checked />
```

You were adding three radio buttons of the same group that were all checked by default, so the last one was overriding the previous two and getting the red class

But mainly for the actual answer, do not include checked as an attribute and apply the javascript as an onclicked event, or only add the checked to a single element
here is an example of an onclick event:
http://jsfiddle.net/7kbLf/2/

Answer (score 0):

If the Radio Button contains the checked attribute . Then it is by default **checked**..

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="hello" checked>  // Checked by default.
```

So remove the checked property for other two RadioButtons.. if you don't do so because of the syntax the last item with **checked property** is checked by default..

```
<div class="holder"> 
    <span>some text</span> 
    <input type="radio" name="test_capability" value="primary" /> 
</div>
<div class="holder">
   <span>some text</span>
   <input type="radio" name="test_capability" value="primary" checked="checked"/> 
</div>
<div class="holder"> 
    <span>some text</span> 
    <input type="radio" name="test_capability" value="primary" />
 </div>
```

If you set the HTML this way your approach should work..

```
$('.holder span').each(function() {
    var spanElement = $(this);
    if (spanElement.nextAll(':radio:first').is(':checked')) {
        spanElement.addClass("red");
    }
});

// Change event 
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    $('span').removeClass('red');

    if( this.checked){
        $(this).closest('div.holder').find('span').addClass('red');
    }
});
```

**[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/MR2EL/)**